# Can not launch agent in windows 10 when running agent.jar via batch command

Tags: java, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run one of my Jenkins agent which is based on windows 10 via running agent.jar using batch script.

What I did :
My batch file is in the same folder with agent.jar folder
I created the shortcut for the my batch file and placed it inside Microsoft/Windows/Startup folder so that every time computer reboots the agent.jar file execute via batch file

Upon running the file i am getting following warning from jenkins in my cmd and agent also not going online

WARNING: Are you running slave agent from an interactive console?
If so, you are probably using it incorrectly.
See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launching+slave.jar+from+from+console
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>rO0ABXNyABpodWRzb24ucmVtb3RpbmcuQ2FwYWJpbGl0eQAAAAAAAAABAgABSgAEbWFza3hwAAAAAAAAAB4=??

My batch file contains:

```
@ECHO ON
start java -jar C:\Jenkins\agent.jar
echo "The program has been completed"
```

Why I am getting this warning , because it is not working every time i have to run agent.jar file via cmd manually when i my agent machine restart , Is there trick the my agent runs automatically after restarts so I can get rid of this manual exercise

Comment: Because you are using it incorrectly, like the error message states. Let me go find some of my automation scripts I used and show you.

Comment: but that same script when i run manually it works , i know something i m missing but not exactly reaching towards the error point

Comment: `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar "C:\Jenkins\agent.jar" -jnlpUrl http://<JENKINS-SERVER>:8080/jenkins/computer/<devicename>/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret> -workDir "<workdir>"` That would be a normal way, you need to extract the secret key, which can be done simply by some tricks.

Comment: I have secret key to launch jenkins agent , so what i understood is i have to change my bat file ? some thing like this :
start "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar "C:\Jenkins\agent.jar" -jnlpUrl http://<JENKINS-SERVER>:8080/jenkins/computer/<devicename>/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <secret> -workDir "<workdir>"

Comment: yes, but obviously changing the values in `<>` fields to reflect your actual values.

Comment: then to automate the startup (on system start) you can use `schtasks` something like this. `schtasks /create /tn "JenkinsAgent" /tr "C:\Jenkins\agentStart.cmd" /sc onstart /ru "SYSTEM" /np /f` where the `AgentStart.cmd` would reflect your batch-file with path. Then once of run: `schtasks /Run /TN "JenkinsAgent"` as initial startup.

Comment: Also that should be `start "" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar …`. Please note that you do need those empty double-quotes, and do not be lazy, use the extension `.exe`, as I have, it removes doubt, as to what is being run, and improves the speed too.

Comment: When I run the following command i am getting following error
"-jar" can not be found
Here is my batch command : start "" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -jar "C:\Jenkins\agent.jar" -jnlpUrl http://localhost:7070/computer/test1/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 9a505463f64da16773784ce8ec0ae08f2cf79e9121cd20aafeab8ccd1a50d6b1 -workDir "C:\Jenkins\"

Comment: I just added .exe in the end of java 
start "" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Jenkins\agent.jar" -jnlpUrl localhost:7070/computer/test1/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 9a505463f64da16773784ce8ec0ae08f2cf79e9121cd20aafeab8ccd1a50d6b1 -workDir "C:\Jenkins\"
Cmd prompt and my script ends but still my agent is offline